# Error using ggmap mapdist() and write back to tibble

Tags: r, ggmap

Trying to get with a batch some routedistances with `mapdist`. In the Variable "von" are my adresses.

```
gtib = mapdist(from=von, to=nach, mode='transit', output='simple')
```

and write it back to a tibble-table (if it would be a dataframe it is also ok).

Tried with 10 addresses and it worked fine. The output is a tibble. When I would like to pass my hole list of addresses then it stucks. Do not have experience with tibbles and I don't understand the error-messages (see below). I guess there is some problem with some addresses, maybe Google can not find and tibble has a problem with that with its matrixsize?

This is one example before I get the error:
Source : https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?origins=Z%C3%BCrchese+9,+H%C3%BCton&destinations=Z%C3%BCrich+HB&key=xxx&mode=transit

```
Fehler: Can't recycle `..1` (size 266) to match `..2` (size 253).
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.
> rlang:last_error()
Fehler: Objekt 'rlang' nicht gefunden
> rlang::last_error()
<error/vctrs_error_incompatible_size>
Can't recycle `..1` (size 266) to match `..2` (size 253).
Backtrace:
 1. ggmap::mapdist(from = von, to = nach, mode = "transit", output = "simple")
 6. vctrs::stop_incompatible_size(...)
 7. vctrs:::stop_incompatible(...)
 8. vctrs:::stop_vctrs(...)
Run `rlang::last_trace()` to see the full context.
> rlang::last_trace()
<error/vctrs_error_incompatible_size>
Can't recycle `..1` (size 266) to match `..2` (size 253).
Backtrace:
    x
 1. +-ggmap::mapdist(from = von, to = nach, mode = "transit", output = "simple")
 2. | \-`%>%`(...)
 3. +-dplyr::mutate(., mode = mode)
 4. +-dplyr::bind_cols(from_to_df, .)
 5. | \-vctrs::vec_cbind(!!!dots, .name_repair = .name_repair)
 6. \-vctrs::stop_incompatible_size(...)
 7.   \-vctrs:::stop_incompatible(...)
 8.     \-vctrs:::stop_vctrs(...)
```